# Modifying /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: networking, dhcp, static-ip

I'm actually in a cafe (similar to Starbuck, Tim Horton, **Second Cup**) where the router is likely protected. My ip address is currently `10.0.x.x`, but I'd like to get a static network (with an ip address similar to `192.168.x.x`) in modifying `/etc/network/interfaces`.

[image]

[image]

If I want to get `inet 192.168.120.1`, how could I modify this file such as it works?

```
auto lo             #automatically activates lo
iface lo inet loopback      #lo with 127.0.0.1 address 
auto eth0           #automatically activates eth0
iface eth0 inet static      #eth0 with static config.
  address 192.168.120.1     #sets IP address
  netmask                   #sets subnet mask
  broadcast                 #sets broadcast address
  network                   #sets network address
  gateway                   #sets default router
```

Thanks for your help!

---

I wanted "to SSH" a virtual machine, but I think I need a network ID starting with `192.168.x.x` instead of `10.0.x.x`.

Comment: You can not do it. You have to use the cafe sub-net.

Comment: She can if she hacks the cafe router and change the ip from there.

Comment: @DougSmythies I don't have a lot of experience with network configurations. Could you explain what do you means, and how to find the cafe subnet available?

Comment: @TatakaiWasumi  Could you tell me how you'd do it?

Comment: It's the only way to do what you want to do but it's against the law. Sorry I can't help.

Comment: Well, I assume you were originally using DHCP, and so the cafe router gave you an IP address to use within its local IP address range. You can not mess with that. Although, that is a very strange sub-net mask, way way way to broad for any typical cafe.

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145997/trying-to-ssh-to-local-vm-ubuntu-with-putty It should help you. You need to do some port forwarding apparently. Another link on how to setup port fowarding: http://www.howtogeek.com/122641/how-to-forward-ports-to-a-virtual-machine-and-use-it-as-a-server/

Comment: Oh, that it is a VM is rather an important bit of information. I read your other question. Once the VM is bridged (which is what I always do also), then everything should be on the 192.168.?.? sub-net and everything should be easy.

Comment: What makes you think that you need an IP address from the 192.168.0.0/16 range to access a VM over SSH and an address from the 10.0.0.0/8 range won't work? Have you tried it? Is the VM hosted on the system connected to the wireless network of the cafe or do you need to access it over the internet?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of manipulating your routing table, you could create a virtual [host-only network](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly) for your virtual machine (or machines).  (I use VirtualBox; I'm not sure if the same feature exists in other virtualization software, but I'd be surprised if it didn't.)  A host-only network is a private virtual network that connects the host to the virtual machines on the network.  When a virtual machine that uses a host-only network is fired up, a network interface is fired up for the host system.  It's similar to a loopback interface, because it's created in software and there is no hardware, but instead of merely looping back packets, it connects to all the virtual machines on the host-only network.

If the virtual machine needs access to the internet then it usually has two network interfaces, one for NAT and one for the host-only network.  The advantage of a host-only network over a bridged network is that you can configure the IP addresses of virtual machines on the host-only network however you like, so a static network with 192.168.x.x addresses would be fine.  I use a host-only network so that I can share files between the host and my virtual machines using Samba, and one would let you connect to your virtual machine using ssh.

Comment: Honnestly, I'm not sure what is supposed to do. If I have two computer  (VM and simple "Ubuntu OS"), could I SSH the VM with the other machine in using host-only network on the virtual machine?

Comment: Yes, that would work. To do it, first create the host-only network in VirtualBox (not in the VM). Then in the VM, activate the second network adapter and connect it to the host-only network.